# How to show dynamically text, from various inputs with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show text on my page, based on one text input and four select inputs.
What is the proper code to dynamically show it, right after the user has chosen any of the inputs? If I write the first input: "Bread" and a select tag with option "Onion", the output should be: Bread Onion. If I choose to select another select option, it should refresh it automatically: Bread Tomato.

```
<input type="text" id="text1">

<select id="cat1">
    <option>Onion</option>
    <option>Tomato</option>
</select>

<p class="show"></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#text1").keyup(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var cat1 = $("#cat1").val();
            $(".show").html(val + " " + cat1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What you are doing it right. What's happening?

Comment: The other select tags are binded to the first input. I want them to change, if I choose a select option AFTER I write into the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate function for joining both and call them on two occasions:

1. On `keyup`.
2. On select `change`.

**See the below Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chng = function() {
    var text = $("#text1").val();
    var cat = $("#cat1").val();
    $(".show").html(text + " " + cat);
  };
  $("#text1").keyup(chng);
  $("#cat1").change(chng);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />

<select id="cat1">
  <option>Onion</option>
  <option>Tomato</option>
</select>

<p class="show"></p>
```

If you want the text to be displayed **after** you write, then use the `blur` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chng = function() {
    var text = $("#text1").val();
    var cat = $("#cat1").val();
    $(".show").html(text + " " + cat);
  };
  $("#text1").blur(chng);
  $("#cat1").change(chng);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" />

<select id="cat1">
  <option>Onion</option>
  <option>Tomato</option>
</select>

<p class="show"></p>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: @Cyberstaker You are welcome. I have added another example as well. Check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event instead of `keyup` to achieve this and check if input value is empty, check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#cat1").change(function() {
         var val = $("#text1").val();
         if (val==""){
            $(".show").html("Write something before in the input");
         }
         else{
            var cat1 = $(this).val();           
            $(".show").html(val + " " + cat1);
         }
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1">

<select id="cat1">
  <option selected disabled> -- Select Option  --</option>
  <option>Onion</option>
  <option>Tomato</option>
</select>

<p class="show"></p>
```